# The function 'f' should be called on each calculation for consistency

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need to access a function that returns a boolean variable. This function is called on the last bar of the chart from multiple places. Below is a simplified version of my script:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", timeframe="5")

f(i) =>
    var bool h = false
    if (hour[i] != hour[i-1])
        h := true
    h

var a = 0
if (barstate.islast)
    for i = 1 to 10
        if f(i)
            a := 1
            // more code here....

plot (close)
```

I'm encountering the following warning: *"the function 'f' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope."*

Despite moving the function inside the `for` loop or just below the `barstate.islast` line, I couldn't resolve the issue. I received an error I couldn't bypass: *"Syntax error at input '=>'"*.

Could you please advise on how to address this?

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier (and more efficient) to do the calculation in the function right there?

```
var a = 0
if (barstate.islast)
    for i = 1 to 10
        if (hour[i] != hour[i-1])
            a := 1
            // more code here....
```

Comment: No, because as I mentioned in my initial message, I need to access the function from multiple locations in the script (all under the `barstate.islast` condition). Otherwise, I'll have to write the same code multiple times, and it's not just one or two conditional lines. The code above is just an example...